# Simple Web Scraping Javascript Query Selector Question

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

Sorry for the basic question. I know to get the phone number in this situation

```
<span class="ng-star-inserted">(111) 111-1111 (HQ)</span>
```

You would do this

```
text = document.querySelector('span[class="ng-star-inserted"]').innerText;
text
```

But there's some sort of prefix ( I don't know the exact terminology but the _ngcontent-c22 )

```
<span _ngcontent-c22="" class="ng-star-inserted">(111) 1111-1111 (HQ)</span>
```

How would I change my script in this scenario?

Comment: Why do you need to change your script? If you're looking it up by class and the class is there, then that will still fetch the same value, regardless of what other attributes are present.

Comment: There's another 'class="ng-star-inserted"" before the text I want to pull unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `querySelectorAll` or select for the additional attribute:

```js
let el1 = document.querySelectorAll('span.ng-star-inserted')[1];
let el2 = document.querySelector('span.ng-star-inserted[_ngcontent-c22]');

console.log(el1.textContent);
console.log(el2.textContent);
```

```html
<span class="ng-star-inserted">WRONG</span>

<span _ngcontent-c22="" class="ng-star-inserted">(111) 1111-1111 (HQ)</span>
```